# images loaded using next/image isn't shown in storybook

Tags: next.js13, storybook

I'm trying to import an image using next/image provided by next.js 14. The image is shown correctly when using npm run dev. But when we run it on storybook, the image doesn't get loaded.

Here's my code in main.ts file in .storybook

```
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";
import * as path from "path";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {
      nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "../next.config.js"),
      builder: {
        useSWC: true,
      },
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
};
export default config;
```

Here's the story I've written in AdminHeader.stories.tsx

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import AdminHeader from "./AdminHeader";

const meta: Meta<typeof AdminHeader> = {
  title: "App/organisms/headers",
  component: AdminHeader,
  tags: ["autodocs"],
};

export default meta;

type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const AdminHeaderExport: Story = {};
```

This is my AdminHeader.tsx file

```
import * as React from "react";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Badge from "@mui/material/Badge";
import AccountCircle from "@mui/icons-material/AccountCircle";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";
import NotificationsIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Notifications";
import MoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreVert";
import Image from "next/image";

export default function AdminHeader() {
  const menuId = "primary-search-account-menu";

  const mobileMenuId = "primary-search-account-menu-mobile";

  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="transparent">
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography
            variant="h6"
            color={""}
            noWrap
            component="div"
            sx={{ display: { xs: "none", sm: "block" } }}
          >
            Test
          </Typography>
          <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}></Box>
          <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "none", md: "flex" } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show 4 new mails"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <Badge badgeContent={4} color="error">
                <MailIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show 17 new notifications"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <Badge badgeContent={17} color="error">
                <NotificationsIcon />
              </Badge>
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              edge="end"
              aria-label="account of current user"
              aria-controls={menuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <AccountCircle />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ display: { xs: "flex", md: "none" } }}>
            <IconButton
              size="large"
              aria-label="show more"
              aria-controls={mobileMenuId}
              aria-haspopup="true"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <MoreIcon />
            </IconButton>
          </Box>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Image
        src="/app-New.svg"
        alt="Logo"
        width={100}
        height={100}
        sizes="(max-width: 768px) 100vw, 700px"
        priority
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I tried to add image as a option like shown in here.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/nextjs#options

```
// .storybook/main.js
import * as path from 'path';

export default {
  // ...
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/nextjs',
    options: {
      image: {
        loading: 'eager',
      },
      nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../next.config.js'),
    },
  },
};
```

But this shows an error saying, Type '{ nextConfigPath: string; builder: { useSWC: true; }; image: { loading: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'FrameworkOptions'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'image' does not exist in type 'FrameworkOptions'.

Comment: I suspect that their documentation is wrong. Interesting fact: searching for the term `eager` in their repository only outputs the README and some tests not related to the framework options mentioned in the README. So definitely something smells bad.

https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Astorybookjs%2Fstorybook%20eager&type=code

Answer (score 0):

you want add image to storybook, you can do like this

```js
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/nextjs";
import * as path from "path";

const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["../src/**/*.mdx", "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|mjs|ts|tsx)"],
  addons: [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/addon-onboarding",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions",
  ],
  framework: {
    name: "@storybook/nextjs",
    options: {
      nextConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "../next.config.js"),
      builder: {
        useSWC: true,
      },
    },
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: "tag",
  },
  staticDirs: [{from: './yourAssets', to: '/assets/'}]
};
export default config;
```